# BigQuery extract fields from unnested json

Tags: json, google-bigquery, unnest

I am able to extract an array from a json string. But I cannot get a subquery to work to extract
the values from the at array.

The current query goes like this:

```
SELECT 
 JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(dv,'$.items')       as items
from  mytable t
,unnest(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(t.jsonish_field))as dv
  WHERE  t.type='adjustment';
```

This results in the following rows

| items |
| --- |
| {"amount":0.93,"status":"COMPLETED","code":"SMBL"} |
| {"amount":9,"status":"COMPLETED","code":"BDES"} |

I would like to be able to expand items into the columns:
amount, status, code

I have tried using subqueries but I am unable to reference the items fields.

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
select 
  json_value(items, '$.amount') as amount,
  json_value(items, '$.status') as status,
  json_value(items, '$.code') as code
from result
```

with output

[image]

Comment: I assume this is selecting from a subquery? Coud you show the full SQL?

Comment: answer usually as good as question, so - yes, that is selecting from subquery and no, I cannot show full sql as it is not enough information for this!!